# Automating a HTTP POST call

Tags: php, html, http, post, get

I've been seeking for A MONTH - about 30 days :/ - trying to solve this. Nothing up to date solves my problem.

I have an external (made by others) website, with funds information. The body includes a `form` with some `select` elements and a `input` button element, all inside `<table>` `<tr>` `<td>` divisions, as the following example.

One of the last table `<tr>` divisions updates the *Funds Information* section, when the `button1` button is pressed, which is the purpose of the form: showing daily values of funds, by selecting single dates.

```
...
<form name="funds" method="post" action="function.php?fund=f1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="year1" size="1" class="class1">
                    <option label="2014" value="2014" >2014</option>
                    ...
                </select>

                <select name="month1" size="1" class="class1">
                    <option label="Jan" value="01" >Jan</option>
                    ...
                </select>

               <select name="day1" size="1" class="class1" >
                   <option label="01" value="01" >01</option>
                   ...
               </select>

               <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="button1" class="class1" >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ...
            Funds Information
            ...
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> 
...
```

I have some automation functionalities -i.e. Matlab `URLREAD` and `URLREAD2`, `CURL`, etc.-, in order to process **GET** and **POST** calls, but i cannot make this work.

In the browser, by placing:

```
http://www.example.com/function.php?fund1=f1&year1=2014&month1=08&day1=21
```

nothing is shown. Same thing ocurrs through other ways.

Anyone who could help me in understanding how to automate this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried cURL? `curl -X POST -d "year1=2014&month1=08&day1=21" "http://www.example.com/function.php?fund=f1"`

Comment: The reason the URL in the browser doesn't work is because it will issue a GET request. Seeing as the form submits via POST, I'd say the server looks for `$_POST` parameters

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I checked for hidden elements, or other things, but it appears there is something i'm not understanding. Can a simple `post` be used here, or there is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Phil.... you give the key of the problem!...

Finally the proper **POST** call, for example by using `cURL`, is as follows:

```
curl -X POST -d "year1=2014&month1=08&day1=21&btn=Submit" "http://www.example.com/function.php?fund=f1" -o data.html
```

Which achieves the proper syntaxis for the **POST** method, on the given setup, and gets the proper data for the funds on the `data.html` file.

By using a sniffer like Nirsoft [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) -which, given all this painless process, I totally recommend-, the **POST** call parameters can be readily detected like this:

```
POST function.php?fund=f1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: ...text/html info...
Origin: http://www.example.com
User-Agent: ...browser info...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.example.com/function.php?fund=f1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cookie: ...cookie data...

year1=2014&month1=08&day1=04&btn=Submit
```

Note that the `Content-Length` number is the length of the parameter pairs phrase, and most important, the parameter pairs are at the bottom.

Note also that all these table elements dont effect in anything the post call.

Finally, under `URLREAD`, the call is as follows:

```
url='http://www.example.com/function.php?fund=f1';
urlstring={'year1','2014','month1','08','day1','17','btn','Submit'};
data=urlread(url,'post',urlstring);
```

and gets the proper data on the `data` variable.

Best Regards,

hypfco